# Request path does not match a supported file type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to .Net Core MVC. I'm trying to add a controller to an existing project, but I'm getting the error

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[4]
The request path https://localhost:5001/api/admin/... does not match a supported file type
```

This makes me think it's not even getting to the app itself but getting blocked in some kind of middleware somewhere. Or, why does it complain about file type? There's no "type" involved here, it's just a string containing a URL.

In VSCode I added the new controller in the same folder with existing controllers, and the build worked fine. Ctrl-F5 brings it up in my browser and I can run the old APIs (at least the ones that I tried) but not the new one; it gives a 404 if I use a URL to the new controller.

This also has Swagger installed, and Swagger shows the old APIs but not the new one.

In the Startup.cs it has

```
app.UseRouting();
```

and also

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
              endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    areaName: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

              endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default",
                    "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

This is .Net Core 3.1.302 and VSCode 1.48.0 on Windows 10.

I had thought from reading tutorials that all I needed to do to add a controller was to write the code (modeled closely on an existing, working controller) and build it. But there must be some additional step to register or log the new controller somewhere?

Is this the right Configure method? From Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                CreateUserRoles(services).Wait();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

#if Release
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
#endif
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).FullName, "MobileApp.WebPortal", "wwwroot")),
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
            });

            app.UseSession();

            
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/jobs", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new [] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() },
                AppPath = "/"
            });

#if RELEASE
                //app.UseWebMarkupMin();
#endif

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                //endpoints.MapControllers();
                //endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    areaName: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                //endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                //    name: "internaldefault",
                //    areaName: "Internal",
                //    pattern: "Internal/{controller=Patient}/{action}/{id?}");


                //endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                //    name: "identity",
                //    areaName: "Identity",
                //    pattern: "Identity/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default",
                    "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });


            

            //var config = new MapperConfigurationExpression();
            //config.AddProfile(new MapperProfile());
            //Mapper.Initialize(config);

            var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions() { SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2)};
            QueryCacheManager.DefaultMemoryCacheEntryOptions = options;
        }
```

Comment: The `StaticFileMiddleware` thinks it's a file, which is weird. We'll need to see the entire `Configure` method to understand what's going on.

Comment: Good job on your question, new contributor. I've never encountered that error before, but did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42851502/net-core-api-request-does-not-match-a-supported-file-type) post?

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto, where do I find the Configure method?

Comment: @itsme86, I was just now looking at that. I haven't tried ServeUnknownFileTypes = true, but my question would be, why do the old APIs work if this is the problem? That's what seems mysterious here - the old ones work, but the new one which is copied from an old one with just the name changed from UserController to PatientListController, doesn't work. I would think either both of them would be unknown types or they would both work.

Comment: @itsme86, Thanks for your compliment about my question. I think I'm often guilty of not providing enough information on questions like this, so I tried to give the details that might be relevant.

Comment: The `Configure` method is where you have those `app.UseRouting();` and etc in the startup class

Comment: OK, I just tried setting ServeUnknownFileTypes to true in Startup.cs and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I just added the Configure method above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a partial answer to this that I don't entirely understand. I was working in VSCode. I created a new file for my PatientListController and put it in the appropriate place in the file hieracharcy, and got the error messages described above (plus the fact that it didn't show up in Swagger).

But if I work in Visual Studio (which I'm less familiar with), when I attempt to create a new file, it specifically asks me what I am creating and I choose Controller from the list.

In VSCode, apparently it doesn't know what this new file is and so the compiler just ignores it. So the compiled code has no trace of the new controller.

In Visual Studio the compiler knows that I've added a new controller and the exact same code works just fine and the new api shows up in Swagger.

So there must be some way in VSCode to signal what to do with the new file, but I have no idea how to make it do that. And I also don't understand why VSCode functions differently from Visual Studio in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue in VSCode. After 4 hours of going through websites I simply realised that when i added the new controller....I created the file in VSCode without the ".cs" extension!!!!!
So my Controllers directory had 2 files called "AccountsController" and "ReportsController" and one "HomeController.cs"...and funnily enough only the home controller worked.